# Radiative corrections as v.e.v source for spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

For spontaneous symmetry breaking, one would need a term like $L = -\mu^2\phi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4}\phi^4$ in the Lagrangian for a scalar $\phi$.
This leads to a vacuum expectation value (v.e.v)= $\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$.

The below paper by Coleman and Weinberg, proposes radiative corrections as a source of v.e.v. for spontaneous symmetry breaking.
"Radiative Corrections as the origin of Spontaneous symmetry breaking", Phys. Rev. D, 7 (1973)
https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.7.1888

Is radiative corrections, currently, one of the most accepted theory on the source of v.e.v. ?
Are there any known issues or concerns with radiative corrections as a source of v.e.v. ?